# MSBuild (VS2012) fails to find "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition" error

Tags: sql-server, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

When we build our SQLServer project (SSDT for VS2012) the build works.  On attempting to publish we find that we get the above error.  The error is genuine.  Is this a known issue with SSDT builds - it is causing some concern to team members who cannot guarantee the correctness of their code by simply building the solution.

Comment: If you use VS2012 to publish and double-click the error, does it take you to the offending line in the script? The only time I see issues like that would be in some sort of insert/update statement - either in a stored proc/trigger or a pre/post-deploy script. Are you able to publish to a local or new database?

Comment: Yes double click does take us to the problem - and there was a genuine problem.  What surprises us is that "passing the build" is no guarantee that the script will publish sucessfully.

Comment: Did you suppress any warnings along the way? I've seen things like this happen when people start turning off warnings so they don't see them while developing (sometimes legitimately). Also, if this is something that references another DB your reference file for it may be out of date and need to be updated.  Of interesting, if you search for "TSQL Smells" and SSDT you should find a plugin that could help when running code analysis against your project.

Comment: No - we had no suppressions of warnings.  It is simply something that we have had to accept and work around.  There are multiple databases in a large datawarehousing project involved and it is not a common occurrance.  Still it is a little disconcerting!